# Android InputStream Convert to String, get variable

Tags: php, android, sql, inputstream

I have successfully converted http response in Android to String using the Inputstream, using the convertStreamToString (instream).  The question I have is how do I take that converted String and put that into a local String.  Here is the response of the converted String:

```
INSERT INTO androidlogin (user, pass) VALUES ('r','r'){"user":"r","pass":"r"}
```

I would like to retrieve the String for user and pass.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is to create a JSONObject from the string you have, and then do obj.optString("user") so

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(string);
String user = obj.optString("user");

Comment: @ WIIIJBD - that is originally what i tried, but it throws exception each time.  here is my code: InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
      // create new JSON object assign converted data as parameter 
    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));
    String retUser = jsonResponse.getString("user");

Comment: Dont use get. Always use opt. Get will break your code. Also log the string you are getting so you know what it really contains. .optString will simply return null if the key does not exist.

Comment: I mean log the string you are making a jsonobject from. Finally I use ioutil.tostring ro chamge a inputstream to a string.

Comment: Thx WIIIJBD.  I actually removed an echo from my php code and my original JSON worked!!

Comment: Just the same, .opt is most always better than .get   im glad you figured it out